# How can I remove all quotas in node-localstorage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, local-storage, node-local-storage

I'm using node-localStorage, which seems to provide a partial copy of localStorage and its semantics for Node. (You have to use methods like localStorage.getItem('foo') to get and set instead of reading or setting localStorage['foo'], but while it's incomplete it looks like a faithful copy.)

One feature of the original localStorage that has been included in the port is a default 5MB quota, which I don't want in the context I am using.

How can I turn off all quotas for node-localstorage?

Answer (score 2):

To set quota you may pass additional parameter to ctor like this

```
localStorage = new LocalStorage('./scratch', Number.MAX_VALUE);
```

This will guarantee that you never reach maximum.